# Regular expression to extract ID from string

Tags: regex

I have string (more than one line), starting with this sentence. Beginning is the same, but UID is changing.

```
Found Mifare Classic 1k with UID a1b2c3d4.
```

I want to get only ID - **a1b2c3d4** using regex. But I dont know how to extract it.

Comment: which language you want

Comment: basic regular expression syntax will include the ability to group a match - the actual way to extract and utilize that match depends on the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex string would be:

```
.* with UID (.*?)\.
```

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for future reference.

Comment: That is not a very good regular expression for this purpose:
  `^.*? with UID ([a-f0-9]+)` 
Might be better.